# PHP Download file with header

Tags: php, file, header, download

I know it's something easy, but I can't seem to find the solution.
I want to download a pdf from a folder.  The pdf is in a folder named **forms**.
My script is in a different folder.

When I try to download the file with the following code:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="forms/form1976.pdf"');
```

The filename becomes: forms-form1976.pdf. That's not right, the filename should be: form1976.pdf. How do I enter the the correct folder first?

Comment: An explanation of JTC's answer below. `header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.pdf');` is the name of the file to be "saved as", and can be any other name (with respective extension). However, `readfile("/path/to/yourfile.pdf");` is the actual file on your server itself. Just a quick "FYI" ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.pdf');
readfile("/path/to/yourfile.pdf");
```